# Exchange server - Save copy of outgoing email message in a public folder

Tags: exchange-server

What I would like to achieve is:

Automatically save a copy of all outgoing (sent) email messages sent in the name of certain users (MyUserInPR@MyServer.com) to a certain public folder.

The purpose of this is to have a readonly view of all sent email messages available to every other user.

What would be the best way of achieving described above in Microsoft Exchange 2003 and 2007?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For exchange 2007 SP1 and greater the best way is to use Exchange Web Services. I have written an article on my blog ([C#: Getting All Emails From Exchange using Exchange Web Services](http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=454)) which can help.

Otherwise the Exchange forum is a great place to ask [Exchange Server Forums > Development](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/threads).